# not getting any response from router to controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

[image: Post section image]
[image: command prompt]

### login.controller

```
angular
    .module('app.pages.auth.login')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

/** @ngInject */
function LoginController($http, $location)
{
    var vm = this;

    vm.submitPost =  function(userData){
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/pages/auth/login',
            method: 'POST',
            data: userData
        }).then(function(res) {
            if(res.data.success){
                $location.path('/pages/profile');
                console.log(res.data.message);
                //vm.message=res.data.message;
            } else {
                //console.log(res.data.message);
                //vm.message=res.data.message;
                $location.path('/pages/auth/login');
            }
        }, function(error) {
            alert('here');
        });
    };   
}
```

### api.js

```
router.get('/pages/auth/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.flash('loginMessage'));
    res.render('auth/login/login.html', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
});

router.get('/pages/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

    return res.json({
            success:true,
            //message: 'Login Success',
    })
    res.render('profile/profile.html', {user:req.user }); 
});
```

> I am not getting any response from router to controller. It shows the alert message 'here'. Is there any thing wrong done here? please help me to fix this.

### login.html

```
<form name="loginForm">
        <div class="alertmessage" >{{vm.message}}</div>
            <md-input-container flex md-no-float>
                <input ng-model="vm.form.username" placeholder="Username" translate
                       translate-attr-placeholder="LOGIN.USERNAME" name="username" required="true">
                       <div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" ng-show="loginForm.username.$touched">
                            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                        </div>
            </md-input-container>


            <md-input-container flex md-no-float>
                <input ng-model="vm.form.password" type="password" placeholder="Password" translate
                       translate-attr-placeholder="LOGIN.PASSWORD" name="password" required="true">
                       <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" ng-show="loginForm.password.$touched">
                            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                        </div>
            </md-input-container>

            <div class="remember-forgot-password" layout="row" layout-sm="column"
                 layout-align="space-between center">
                <md-checkbox class="remember-me" ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Remember Me">
                    <span translate="LOGIN.REMEMBER_ME">Remember Me</span>
                </md-checkbox>

                <a ui-sref="app.pages_auth_forgot-password" class="forgot-password md-accent-color"
                   translate="LOGIN.FORGOT_PASSWORD">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>

            <md-button class="md-raised md-accent" aria-label="LOG IN" translate="LOGIN.LOG_IN"
                       translate-attr-aria-label="LOGIN.LOG_IN"
                       ng-click="vm.submitPost(vm.form);">
                LOG IN
            </md-button>
        </form>
```

Comment: do u see any error on console. If yes please share it.

Comment: In the console i am getting only username and password given by me in the post section but in response i didn't get anything.

Comment: could you please help to how to add images here?

Comment: r u seeing the logger u have given in the success?

Comment: In the logger its not showing anything?

Comment: from where userData is coming? R u passing it from the html?

Comment: Yes i am passing it from html.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify what is the value of 'userData' coming from the front end/from where u r calling it. Seems there is an issue with that only!

If thats not the issue then please check the network in developer tools that why your service is failing?

> To go to network(on chrome) click F12 >> Network.

Verify your service call and see whats the issue!

EDIT:

> where is your 'headers' in service call? You intentionally din't add or you missed it?

Comment: userData showing  Object { username="Kevin",  password="kevin"} these values given by me.

Comment: I didn't get any 'res' value from api.js, that's y it is directly go to function(error) {
   alert('here');
}

Comment: why u din't added headers?

Comment: sir actually i am doing this project using this link(https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local). But in that they don't use any controller and headres

Comment: have u checked in the network? I asked u to do if u see the above post! Share the screenshot of network tab.

Comment: i can't uploading the image bcoz i don't have sufficient reputation in this. How to add image in comment section?please help me

Comment: post it as an answer.. probably u can do that by that way!

Answer (score 0):

### [This is one more image of network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGNfY.png)When i click after login it showed like this

[image: When i click after login it showed like this]

### Network tab image showing like this

[image: Network tab image showing like this]

Comment: share the screenshot after u click the login. U need to open the network tab and then login(whatever u were trying to do) so that service call gets done.

Comment: added that image also sir.

Comment: R u sure ur login service call is getting done? I could not see any service call in the screenshot!

Comment: one more image i have added sir